# How to Send your URL to a friend to start a video call using flask-socketio

Tags: flask-socketio

I am using [this tutorial](https://github.com/pjpygit/webrtc-videochat) for video call using flask-socketio in flask mysql to make application. In it 
 
*room_id* = generate random (templates/home.html) 
*display_name* = session[username] (templates/chatroom_checkpoint.html)

After that I have to send invitation with room_id & display_name to the other user.
I want to do as below 
user_1 want to video call with user_2 
After generate room_id and display_name 
a window open on user_2 screen:
user_1 want to video call with you... 
*link of room_id to join* and *link to disconnect*

There is also one page using https://www.scaledrone.com 
https://pjpygit.github.io/webrtc/simple_webrtc_video.html 
Now my question: How to Send your URL to a friend to start a video call using flask-socketio

Answer (score 0):

Sent url for video call as message to friend using this tutorial https://github.com/pjpygit/flask-socketio-example. Its working.